# How can use :contains() Selector to determine the object has a certain keyword when it is clicked?

Tags: jquery, contains, contain

How can use `:contains` to find the object has a certain keyword when it is clicked?

```
<a href="#" class="click">&#187; Read More</a>

$('.click').click(function() {

   if($(":contains('More')", this)) alert('1');

});
```

I get the alert whenever it contains the keyword or not... how can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is) to see if an element matches your `:contains` selector:

```
$(".click").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":contains('More')")) {
        alert('1');
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/3N8ek/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".click:contains('More')").click(function() {

   alert('1');

});
```

Comment: thanks but I need to find the keyword after the click event - not when the click even happens. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You are always getting `alert` because you are not checking for `length` property of jQuery object. jQuery always returns at least an empty object when it do not find any match. So `if($(":contains('More')", this))` will always return `true` no matter what.

```
$('.click').click(function() {

   if ($(this).is(":contains('More')")) {
     alert('1');
   }

});
```

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: This will not work. Your selector means "find all elements that contain "More" underneath the clicked element).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if($(this + ':contains("More")')) alert('1');
```

See [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)-docs for more on the usage.